# Microsoft Sync Framework Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to Sync my local database with an online one using Microsoft Sync Framework but it gives an invalid cast exception when try to sync the .SDF file it shows the following error message at that certain line of code.

```
Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
        Me.InitializeSyncProviders()
        Me.InitializeSyncTables
        Me.OnInitialized
    End Sub
```

The exception is thrown when the second line of above code is executed behind the initializesyncproviders().The function has following code behind it

```
 <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()> _
    Private Sub InitializeSyncProviders()
        'Create SyncProviders.
        Me.RemoteProvider = New LocalDataCache1ServerSyncProvider()
        'Dim serverConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=RSERVER-PC; Initial Catalog=ST_TOKA_04; Integrated Security=false;user=sa;password=123")
        'Me.RemoteProvider = New SqlSyncProvider("godownSyncTableSyncGroup", serverConn)
        Me.LocalProvider = New LocalDataCache1ClientSyncProvider()
    End Sub
```

Function it gives error on this certain line.

```
Me.RemoteProvider = New LocalDataCache1ServerSyncProvider()
```

Comment: What `type` is `Me.RemoteProvider`? The error is pretty clear.

Comment: Well Man its built in code provided by Microsoft I can't understand what error it is giving.....And whats the reason of it... @EBrown

Comment: can you post the actual exception/ stack trace? and can you post the code where you're setting the providers and actually calling the sync?